# Heroku app must now use github. Does it still nee to have the git@heroku.com remote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I've got an app on heroku, but the time has come to leverage github.

I've ran

```
$ git rm remote origin
```

and added the github repo as the master.  I've pushed up to github.

But when i run

```
$ git remote -v
```

it lists the github repo, but it still also list the remote at git@heroku.com.

Do I need to remove the `git@heroku.com` remote in order to have heroku always pull off of my github repo when launching the app?

Comment: Where have you read that it **need** to use GitHub? My app has close code and don't have GH repo and work normally. Also, may I ask you why you have Heroku repo as your origin? Heroku repo should be write-only.

Comment: You don't *need* github. But the app is going to be worked on by group of developers, instead of just one.  Github makes that collaborative work easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have as many local remotes as you want and it won't effect what Heroku does.

Comment: But in this case, I do want to affect what Heroku does.  I want it to use the github repo as the source of all the code.  I'm worried that having the git@heroku.com remote will keep heroku from pulling from the github account.

Comment: Heroku does not pull, you push to it. Remotes are local to your repo, so you do not have to worry about Heroku. If you have Github as you `origin` remote, and heroku as the `heroku` remote, `git push`/`git pull` will default to origin. To push code to github, use `git push`, and to push code to Heroku, use `git push heroku` (this will only work if you set your repo to track Github, with `git push -u origin master`).